# how to add a value to the date field using data frame in spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I have date values some (yyyy/mm/dd) on my dataframe. i need to find the next 7 days of data. How can i do it using dataframe in spark

for example: I have data like below

```
   23/01/2018 , 23
   24/01/2018 , 21
   25/01/2018, 44
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   29/01/2018,17
```

I need to get the next 7 days of data including today(starting from minimum date from the data). so in my example i need to get dates 2018/01/23 plus 7 days ahead. is there any way to achieve the same ?

Note: i need to find minimum date from the data and need to filter that minimum date + 7 days of data

```
         scala> df.show
          +----------+---+-------+
          | data_date|vol|channel|
          +----------+---+-------+
          |05/01/2019| 10|    ABC|
          |05/01/2019| 20|    CNN|
          |06/01/2019| 10|    BBC|
          |07/01/2019| 10|    ABC|
          |02/01/2019| 20|    CNN|
          |17/01/2019| 10|    BBC|
          +----------+---+-------+




         scala>  val df2 = df.select("*").filter( to_date(replaceUDF('data_date)) > date_add(to_date(replaceUDF(lit(minDate))),7))
         df2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [data_date: string, vol: int ... 1 more field]

         scala> df2.show
         +---------+---+-------+
         |data_date|vol|channel|
         +---------+---+-------+
         +---------+---+-------+
```

I need data as below : minimum date is 02/02/2018 a, so minimum date + 7 is 07/02/2018. I need data between 02/01/2018 and 07/02/2018

```
          +----------+---+-------+
          | data_date|vol|channel|
          +----------+---+-------+
          |05/01/2019| 10|    ABC|
          |05/01/2019| 20|    CNN|
          |06/01/2019| 10|    BBC|
          |07/01/2019| 10|    ABC|
          |02/01/2019| 20|    CNN|

          +----------+---+-------+
```

can someone help as i am beginner on spark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import below statement

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Code Snippet

```
    val minDate = df.agg(min($"date1")).collect()(0).get(0)
    val df2 = df.select("*").filter( to_date(regexp_replace('date1,"/","-")) > date_add(to_date(regexp_replace(lit(minDate)),"/","-"),7))
    df2.show()
```

For data

```
val data = Seq(("2018/01/23",23),("2018/01/24",24),("2018/02/20",25))
```

Output would be

```
+----------+---+
|     date1|day|
+----------+---+
|2018/02/20| 25|
+----------+---+
```

If you are looking for different output, please update your question with the expected results.

Below is a complete program for your reference

```
package com.nelamalli.spark.dataframe

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
object DataFrameUDF {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark:SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[3]")
      .appName("SparkByExample")
      .getOrCreate()

    val data = Seq(("2018/01/23",23),("2018/01/24",24),("2018/02/20",25))

    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
    val df = data.toDF("date1","day")

    val minDate = df.agg(min($"date1")).collect()(0).get(0)
    val df2 = df.select("*").filter( to_date(regexp_replace('date1,"/","-")) > date_add(to_date(regexp_replace(lit(minDate)),"/","-"),7))

    df2.show()
  }


}
```

Thanks

Comment: bu the thing is first i need to find minimun date from the data and need to filter that minimum date + 7 days of data

Comment: am getting empty results

Comment: But i am still getting empty results :

Comment: Your code is not right, you are missing replaceUDF on condition. please try the code that I've added. and then change it according to your need.

Comment: Updated my results with latest code..still its empty

Comment: Your input date format on your original post is 2018/01/23 format and you are trying with 05/01/2019 which is not compatible. change your date and try.

Comment: could please share that current date + 7 days of calculation logic laso whihc you shared previously

Comment: If you don't mind, could you please create another Post. posting on same will get confused for other readers and we are not supposed to modify accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is still unclear. I'm borrowing the input from @Naveen and you can get the same results without UDFs. Check this out

```
scala> val df = Seq(("2018/01/23",23),("2018/01/24",24),("2018/02/20",25)).toDF("dt","day").withColumn("dt",to_date(regexp_replace('dt,"/","-")))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [dt: date, day: int]

scala> df.show(false)
+----------+---+
|dt        |day|
+----------+---+
|2018-01-23|23 |
|2018-01-24|24 |
|2018-02-20|25 |
+----------+---+

scala> val mindt = df.groupBy().agg(min('dt)).as[(java.sql.Date)].first
mindt: java.sql.Date = 2018-01-23

scala> df.filter('dt > date_add(lit(mindt),7)).show(false)
+----------+---+
|dt        |day|
+----------+---+
|2018-02-20|25 |
+----------+---+


scala>
```

Comment: I have updated my input..is there any way to achieve